# Pass parameter to processbuilder outputstream in different class

Tags: java, processbuilder

I am just trying to control processbuilder inputstream and outputstream from different class

It is main class

```
public class Controller
{
    public static void main(String[]args)
    {
        Runner r=new Runner("Test");
        r.activateInput();
        r.setInput("Test");
    }
}
```

It is other class to run process

```
import java.io.*;
public class Runner
{
    boolean activeInput=true;
    boolean active=true;
    String input;
    public Runner(String command)
    {
        try {
         // create a new process
         System.out.println("Creating Process...");

         ProcessBuilder compile = new ProcessBuilder("java","TestOut");
         compile.directory(new File("C:/Users/abhishek221192/Documents/Socket"));
         Process process = compile.start();

         OutputStream stdin = process.getOutputStream ();
         InputStream stderr = process.getErrorStream ();
         InputStream stdout = process.getInputStream ();

         final BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader(stdout));

         BufferedReader error = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader(stderr));
         final BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(stdin));

         //final Scanner scan=new Scanner(System.in);

           Thread T=new Thread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                while(active)
                {
                    if(activeInput)
                    System.out.println(activeInput+"  "+input);
                    String data ="Abhi";
                    data += "\n";
                    try {
                        if(activeInput){
                        writer.write(data);
                        writer.flush();
                        activeInput=false; 
                      }
                        //
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }

            }
        } );
        T.start();
        T.setName("Input");
            Thread T1=new Thread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
           String line;
         try{
           while ((line = reader.readLine ()) != null) {
                 System.out.println(line);
            }} catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
        }
            } );
        T1.start();
        T1.setName("Output");

         /*   
           String line;
            while ((line = error.readLine ()) != null) {
                 System.out.println(line);
            }
            */
            //stdout.close();

            //error.close();

           //T.stop();
           //stdin.close();
           //System.err.println("stdin closed");
           active=false;
         // close the output stream
         System.out.println("Closing the output stream...");

         //testProcessBuilder();

      } catch (Exception ex) {
         System.out.println("Error"+ex.getMessage());


      }
    }
    public void activateInput()
    {
        this.activeInput=true;
        System.out.println("active"+activeInput);
    }
    public void setInput(String input)
    {
        this.input=input;
    }

}
```

It is TestOut code it include only one input statement

TestOut.java

```
import java.util.*;
public class TestOut
{
   public static void main(String[]args)
   {
      Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
      System.out.println("Output hello TestOut");
      System.out.println("Output1 "+sc.nextLine());
   }
}
```

I am geting this output

```
Creating Process...
true  null
Closing the output stream...
activetrue
Output hello TestOut
Output1 Abhi
```

`r.setInput();` is not setting value

Comment: did you try changing the order of `setInput` and `setActivateInput` ?

Comment: It would not effect it but yes, i have tried it

Comment: Can you please post TestOut code as well ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couple of changes i made to make it work. the main problem with this piece of code is concurrency issues as two threads are working on same set of data. activeInput is being modified by `Controller` and by `thread T`

**Change 1:**

```
public synchronized void activateInput(boolean activate) {
    this.activeInput = activate;
    System.out.println("active" + activeInput);
}

    if (activeInput) {
        writer.write(data);
        writer.flush();
        activateInput(false);
    }
```

declared method `activateInput` `synchronized` and replaced `activateInput = false` with the method call in `thread T`

**Change 2:**

```
//          active = false;
```

commented out this line at the end of `Runner()` method because it is stopping the writer Thread unnecessarily.

**Change 3:**

```
try {
    Thread.sleep(1000);
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
   // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Added this at the end of Writer Thread's while loop to give writer Thread T some breathing space and to give it a chance on reading the values.

**Output:**
Here is the output i got:

```
Creating Process...
activetrue
Output hello TestOut
true  Test
activefalse
Output1 Abhi
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this.but if i will not set active = false;  then process will still running .I want to stop it, please tell some way to do this

Comment: Then you shall also do it from controller class

Comment: Ok let me tell you whole scenerio actually i am going to use these code in jax-rs so that i will be able to run process by ajax from client side and i dont want to make client to close this.  but i have accomplised it by keeping active=false in new thread and sleep this thread for 10 to 15 seconds but i want to use any other way

Comment: You can't keep it where if was currently because that will not allow your writer thread to write. You need to think it in steps. 1. Create Runner  2. Do Processing  3. Stop threads. These three operations has to be called from outside Runner.

Comment: If this answer solved your problem in question then kindly accept as answer. hv fun coding :)